# Upload images without input in python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have python 3.8, using input type = "file" it duplicates the images and it doesn't work correctly. Is there any way to drag the images to the area?

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

url="https://www.milanuncios.com/publicar-anuncios-gratis/media?idanuncio=365084685&contra=3W45"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
userID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@type='file']")
userID.send_keys('foto_1.jpg')
time.sleep(2)
userID.send_keys('foto_2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

After sending each picture, set the value of Input to be "".

There are two ways you could try:

1. clear(), Clears the text if it’s a text entry element.

```py
userID.send_keys('foto_1.jpg')

userID.clear()

userID.send_keys('foto_2.jpg')
```

2. set the value using pure js

```py
userID.send_keys('foto_1.jpg')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", userID)

userID.send_keys('foto_2.jpg')
```

Answer (score -1):

Input field supports multiple files upload (node contains `multiple` boolean attribute), so you can try to upload both files at the same time:

```
userID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@type='file']")
userID.send_keys('foto_1.jpg' + '\n' + 'foto_2.jpg')
```

or

```
userID = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@type='file']")
files = ['foto_1.jpg', 'foto_2.jpg']
userID.send_keys('\n'.join(files))
```